# Changing value of preprocessor symbol for testing

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am writing a dynamically growing string buffer. I have the following in a `.c` file.

```
#ifndef STRBUF_GROWTH_SIZE
#define STRBUF_GROWTH_SIZE 4096
#endif
```

My code uses this constant to do the reallocation of the buffer. Now in the tests, I need to set this value to a small one so that I can check the reallocation. I tried defining this in the `tests.cpp` (All tests are in C++ using UnitTest++).

```
#define STRBUF_GROWTH_SIZE 10
TEST(StringBuffer)
{
    struct strbuf *string = strbuf_init();

    strbuf_add(string, "first");
    CHECK_EQUAL("first", string->buffer);
    CHECK_EQUAL(5, string->length);
    CHECK_EQUAL(10, string->allocated);   /* this fails */

    strbuf_add(string, " second");
    CHECK_EQUAL("first second", string->buffer);
    CHECK_EQUAL(12, string->length);
    CHECK_EQUAL(20, string->allocated); /* this fails */

    strbuf_destroy(string);
}
```

I am wondering why the value didn't change to 10? How can I workaround this problem?

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you're in C++, why on earth are you using such abominable constructs?

Comment: as I said, the testing framework is the only one in C++.

Comment: That's not what he meant.  Your arrow growth algorithm is horrible.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I am sorry, I couldn't get that. Can you please explain what is wrong here?

Comment: @Appu: Your code seems to be pure C, I can see no C++ involved. And in C++ you wouldn't need a string buffer, since you have `std::string` and `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269063/buffer-growth-strategy

Comment: @Hans: Ohh ok. I am already using 1.5 growth factor. Haven't included it in the example to make it simple. The code provided here is only intented for explanation and it is not the production code I have.

Comment: Something is *very* wrong here.

Comment: @Hans : Thanks again. Do you mean the growth factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessing is done on a source-file-by-source-file basis (well, not quite, but it's close enough).  A `#define` in one source file won't affect anything in another source file.

You'll either need to `#define` this in a header, which you can swap out with another header during testing, or you'll need to parameterise your library (e.g. `strbuf_init(int growth_size)`.

Alternatively, why don't you just test with strings that are of length-4096?  Then you'll be testing your actual production code.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about `strbuf_init(int growth_size)`. The problem with that is I need to keep the `growth_size` in a variable and using this from multiple places will overwrite this global value (this code is expected to be thread safe). BTW, keeping this value as a fields in `struct strbuf` works.

Answer (score 4):

The `#define` in your test isn't seen by your code in the other .c file.  However, you can inject the macro in your build.  With gcc its the [-D argument](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html#SEC11).  With msvc's cl its the [/D argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8(v=VS.71).aspx).

Comment: Altho I think that having a runtime parameter (as suggested by Olie Charlesworth's answer) is probably the better way to go.  Injecting the macro is good if for some reason you can't refactor the source.