# unable to uninstall Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to uninstall Visual studio 2012 from my machine but is is not giving me any option for uninstalling the same. When I write click on Visual Studio 2012 in control panel/Program and Features, it shows CHANGE option and when I click on this option it display popup with following option.

Microsoft .Net Framework Required for Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 Setup.

Click Accept and Install to accept Microsoft Framework license Term.

When I click on this option, it doesn't perform anything and dont uninstall it. Can u please suggest me any option to remove it and install it again. This is  licenced copy of the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to completely uninstall Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584912/how-to-completely-uninstall-visual-studio)

Answer (score 8):

You could try forcibly removing VS2012 and all its components
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441#Force

```
1. Download the setup application you used to originally install Visual Studio 2012. If you installed from media, please insert that media.

2. Open a command prompt.

3. Click Run on the Start menu (Start + R).
    a.  Type cmd and press OK (Enter).
    b.  Type in the full path to the setup application and pass the following command line switches: /uninstall /force
    Example: D:\vs_ultimate.exe /uninstall /force

4. Click the Uninstall button and follow the prompts.
```

Comment: Even if I use this option to forcibly remove Visual Studio 2012, it is not working and give me same prompt as above.

Comment: I get this: `Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : uninstall.`

Comment: This worked for me. I did not have the media so I got the iso from [here](http://www.unlockwindows.com/download-visual-studio-2012-rc/) and ran in cmd as admin.

Answer (score 5):

- Download msiinv.zip from the following location 
  https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=27e6a35d1a492af7&id=27E6A35D1A492AF7%21910&authkey=!ANs8Pr0aVhaT_qQ
- Extract the contents of msiinv.zip to the folder c:\msiinv on your
  system
- Click on the Start menu, choose Run, type cmd and click OK
- Type this command:  c:\msiinv\msiinv.exe -p >
  c:\msiinv\msiinv_output.txt

Note: This command must be run from a cmd prompt or it will not create a log file as expected.
These steps will create a text file named c:\msiinv\msiinv_output.txt with a list of each product that Windows Installer thinks is installed on the system.  Then you can open the text file in any text editor and search the list of products for the name of the product that you want to uninstall.

Output in the  text file will be displayed like this:

Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Beta 2
Product code: {7A1ADD0C-17F3-47B8-B033-A06E189C835D}
Product state: (5) Installed.
Package code: {856D48D2-6F94-466D-9732-534DB5854FB3}
Version: 2.0.50215

Now we have the Windows Installer product code and we can use that to uninstall the product by running msiexec /x {product code} (make sure that you include the curly braces in this command line).  If the product is actually installed on your system you will see a progress screen and uninstall will complete.

If Windows Installer thinks that the product is installed but it really isn't, then running msiexec /x  will give you an error stating that this command is only valid for installed products.  If this happens, you will need to perform an extra step to remove the data that causes Windows Installer to think this product is installed.  You can download the Windows Installer Cleanup Utility and install and run it on your machine to fix this.

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/07/01/434814.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the installer disk, you can run the following command and it removes everything except for a few of the SQL 2012 apps stayed when I ran it.

**vs_ultimate.exe /uninstall /force**

or in my case

**vs_premium.exe /uninstall /force**

Here is the link to the Microsoft article on the topic, and the article lists all the installed applications so if you need to manually remove some you have a list to go off of.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2771441#Force

Comment: uninstall option doesn't exist for Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

Windows update service is using that log file. Do as follows:

1. Type services.msc in run
2. check for windows update service and stop the service.
3. go to C:\windows\windows update.log file and check the properties. The file should have read\write rights. (Note this is a operating system file.You need to make it visible in files and folder option first.)
4. Now try to uninstall the Package.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use a CCleaner programs (Bing it)

Goto "tools" menu on the bottom left > Uninstall > Select "Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012" then click "Run Uninstaller"

Finish.

Comment: using ccleaner does not help!