# Full uninstall of Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I know that the regular uninstall available through Windows 10 for installing and uninstalling programs leaves "bread crumbs" in both the C:\Users subdirectory and the registry. I had to do this for Visual Studio 2019 when I uninstalled it but I do not know the equivalent instructions for VS2012.

Does anyone know any specifics with regards to this?

Comment: This is what I Googled and tried ... i couldn't get it to work.  Forcibly removing Visual Studio 2012: Download the setup application you used to originally install Visual Studio 2012. Open a command prompt. Type in the full path to the setup application and pass the following command line switches: /uninstall /force. Click the Uninstall button and follow the prompts.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 is famous with its bad uninstaller. There are more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19749891/259206), maybe you would find something useful.