# Can't install C# express 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Basically started learning programming and In this tutorial http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=15&number=1
it says to program in c# you need to download C# express 2010, Now i tried installing it and it gives me this error: "Please uninstall all products listen below and then restart setup"
- Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express Beta - ENU

Thing is... I Don't even have that program installed? Don't know what I can do about this.
Also, I noticed this is a very old software and its from 2010, I tried looking for newer versions they all can't run on Windows XP (which is what I have) so I'm stuck with having to install C# express 2010. any help?

Comment: @Jason He said he only has XP, and it won't run on that

Comment: run appwiz.cpl, make _sure_ you don't have any VS2010 beta stuff installed, if you do uninstall it.

Comment: @Jason, he is using Windows XP and cannot install VS2013 because it will require .NET 4.5, which requires Windows Vista or later.

Additionally, I believe this offtopic.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have the beta version of Visual Basic 2010 Express installed on your machine. You'll need to remove that and then attempt to reinstall Visual C# 2010 Express. If plan on using Visual Basic 2010 Express then I would find the non-beta version and install that afterward.

You can download both versions [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads#d-2010-express). I hope this helps.

**Update:** If this doesn't work download the Visual Studio removal utility from [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall) and follow the instructions on the same page. I suggest using the "Complete" removal option the tool provides: **VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe /full /netfx**. Then reinstall.

Comment: I have already uninstalled all of the Visual Basics i had, and it still says that i have it installed :S

Comment: Download the Visual Studio uninstall utility from http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall. That should do the trick.

Comment: Ran it and it said it uninstalled it, still get the same message when i try to install C# express 2010:
 "Please uninstall all products listen below and then restart setup" - Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express Beta - ENU

Comment: When using the removal tool be sure to use the "Complete" mode which wipes out anything associated with Visual Studio 2010 such as supporting components, etc. If that doesn't do the trick then you are experiencing some kind of registry problem.

Comment: I don't have a 'Complete' mode.. just uninstall button when i run the remover.

Comment: The documentation states the run the tool via the command prompt like this for a complete removal: VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe /full /netfx.

Comment: Also, it may help to reboot after performing the uninstall.

Comment: I'm sorry but you've lost me there. How do I run this via the command prompt? *caution I will sound like a massive noob* I tried doing Run > cmd > typing "VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe /full /netfx" there but it failed.

Comment: To make things easy, copy VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe to c:\. From the command prompt, type "cd c:\". Once you are at the root of the drive, then type "VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe /full /netfx". Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Done that, said it uninstalled everything. tried to install C# express 2010 and got the same message :  "Please uninstall all products listen below and then restart setup" - Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express Beta - ENU

Comment: It looks like you may have to start from scratch with a clean OS install. Take a look at this other question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584912/how-to-completely-uninstall-visual-studio/14056815#14056815.

Comment: So the only solution is to Reinstall my OS? That's a shame as i can't do that... Are there any other programs besides C# Express 2010 that i can use to program in C# That's compatible with windows xp?

Comment: I'd try MonoDevelop (http://monodevelop.com/) or xacc.ide (http://xacc.wordpress.com/). Both are free and work with C#/.NET.