# Where do I find Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uninstallation

The Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility was available on http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall. Nevertheless, this page is currently retired (unavailable). Does anyone know where can I find this program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to completely uninstall Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584912/how-to-completely-uninstall-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it on hard drive and uploaded to Dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rqb8hnuksxua5x/VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe

Answer (score 1):

You can try this link it might help you
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2010/08/23/visual-studio-2010-uninstall-utility.aspx

Comment: Your link just links to the URL in the question, which has been called out as broken.

Comment: There *are* links posted in the comments to that blog post, so it is *sort of* useful. But these links should be incorporated into the answer.

Comment: Link is updated by the author of the article as of 19th aug 2014 - http://aka.ms/vs2010uninstall