# How to uninstall Visual Studio 2012 from command prompt

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

Just bought a laptop and want to put Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 on it, but it takes forever to do anything.

My first time installing it, it got stuck on a very common problem.  `Web Deploy 3.0 - Certificate warning or Unable to locate package source error`.  Since the installation crashed, I installed Web Deploy 3.5 (the latest version) manually to get around this issue.

When I try and install again, it says I need to uninstall or repair first.  However, it won't uninstall or repair.  For repair, it sat on `Creating a system restore point` all night` and for uninstall it sat on something I can't remember the other night.

Is it possible to uninstall Visual Studio 2012 via the command prompt and what are the commands to do that?

Comment: I suggest a recovery tool (google for "uninstaller") like Revo or something similar. Anyway answering with suggestions for programs is off-topic here, also your question is probably more suited to superuser.com. Good luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584912/how-to-completely-uninstall-visual-studio this link may help you!

Comment: Well, you got a system restore point for the first failed install.  It creates these expressly to give you a chance to recover.  So use it to restore your machine.