# uninstalling visual studio with all its versions and cleaning registers

Tags: regedit

I've just uninstalled visual studio 2010, 2012 and 2013 of my computer in order to install them later. Now I just want to clean the registers related to them but don't know if I there are some that I have not to delete.
How can I proceed exactly?! 
Any suggestions plz?

Comment: Have you even tried googling first? For instance: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584912/how-to-completely-uninstall-visual-studio-2010) popped up immediately.

Comment: Of course I did but what I undrestood is that it's better to just use the ccleaner and do not delete all the registers and that's what I did but opening the regedit window I still find the same registers. I think I didn't understand what to do !! So if u can help me that would be nice ! -_-