# 'iostream': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installation of Visual Studio 2010 (any edition) installs only 2 files in the C++ headers directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460307/installation-of-visual-studio-2010-any-edition-installs-only-2-files-in-the-c)

I am so desperate Right now its not funny I have searched the entire internet for the answer and its not working.... i have installed and reinstalled  visual studio 2010 pro at least 4 times and it doesnt fix anything..... heres my problem

I try to make a simple Hello world project and boom it fails saying this..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
  cout << "Hello World.." << endl;
  return 0;
}

1>------ Build started: Project: ds, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 1/21/2013 12:31:36 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\ds.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  d.cpp
1>c:\users\dj\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ds\ds\d.cpp(1): fatal error C1083:
Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.32
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

my include folder in VC only has these names
ammintrin
omp
pgobootrun
srv
wmiatlprov

Im not to great with this so if ur gonna answer can you put it noob terms:)
Thank you in advance..

Comment: `my include folder in VC only has these names ammintrin omp pgobootrun srv wmiatlprov` o.O

Comment: have you solved this case?

Answer (score 0):

When you choose console aplication check the option: include precompiled header, most likely you created an empty project in which case you must manualy add the path to iostream file

in .vcxproj directory includes you should have:
Include Directories $(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;
and
Library
$(VCInstallDir)lib;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib;$(WindowsSdkDir)lib;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\lib

if you have these and stdafx.h include in cpp but still no path to iostream you should check PATH environment variable not to be broken or any of the variables $(VCInstallDir) $(WindowsSdkDir) $(FrameworkSDKDir)

Comment: how do i check this part... you have these and stdafx.h include in cpp but still no path to iostream you should check PATH environment variable not to be broken or any of the variables $(VCInstallDir) $(WindowsSdkDir) $(FrameworkSDKDir)