# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 not installing with Include and Lib directory files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, include-path

I can't seem to find a solution for this issue. I've uninstalled and reinstalled VS10 over and over, removed my version of VS11, any redistributables and SDKs I could find. Basically I can't write or compile any basic Visual C++ programs, and when I looked on my hard disk inside the Include directory, there's only two headers - srv.h and wmiatlprov.h. I'm not sure what else is missing, but has anyone experienced this before and found a solution? It seems as though the VS installer is skipping right over those files during the install.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installation of Visual Studio 2010 (any edition) installs only 2 files in the C++ headers directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460307/installation-of-visual-studio-2010-any-edition-installs-only-2-files-in-the-c)