# Header files iostream not found Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I installed visual studio 2010 ultimate version and everything worked perfectly fine and my development environment worked well.

However I had a recent problem in which every piece of code gives me the error about header files not being found like `iostream` `stdio.h` `conio.h` etc.

I pinpointed the problem to it being caused by me uninstalling visual C++ express 2010 that I had installed previous to the installation of the visual studio 2010.

I tried to completely uninstall and install Visual Studio but it seems some files are always left that I cannot track. I used this link and the answer marked right over there to no avails. Can anybody advise me how to get it right without formatting the whole system.

[Link to Question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b8543ffb-7c4f-4b9e-8a6a-0dd195e8f680/installation-did-not-install-header-files?forum=Vsexpressvc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installation of Visual Studio 2010 (any edition) installs only 2 files in the C++ headers directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460307/installation-of-visual-studio-2010-any-edition-installs-only-2-files-in-the-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have solved the problem using another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460307/installation-of-visual-studio-2010-any-edition-installs-only-2-files-in-the-c) on Stack overflow.
The answer points to this [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774158/re-installed-visual-studio-2010-and-c-standard-headers-are-missing) from Microsoft Connect.

The steps I followed to solve the problem are listed below.

Uninstalled visual c++ using the following [vs2010_uninstall tool](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall) from Microsoft and used the switches /full /netfx while uninstalling(use command line instead of double click) as follows: `VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe /full /netfx`

Uninstall Visual Studio Service Pack 1 if its installed

Start Registry Editor in Windows: Win+R type Regedit to open Registry Editor. Do remember to backup your registries and create a restore point.

Search for the key named `PaddedVersion`

If the search key is found and look at keys ending with `VisualStudio\10.0\VC\Libraries` or `VisualStudio\10.0_Config\VC\Libraries`

Delete all keys and subkeys under the `VisualStudio\10.0\VC\Libraries` or if that doesn't work delete all keys and subkeys under `VisualStudio\10.0` or `VisualStudio\10.0_Config`. The catch here is that all keys must be deleted regardless of their prefix to the above mentioned string as HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE or HKEY_USERS etc. It has to be deleted in all cases.

Note the `PaddedVersion` just helps you in finding all such keys.

Once done restart(not compulsory but better if you do it) Windows. Now you are ready to begin re-installation of your version of Visual Studio 2010.

Hope it helps all who are having such a problem..

Comment: Following the instructions solves my problem of upgrading to VS2010 ultimate from VS2010 professional.

Answer (score 0):

After trying this, and countless other solutions over the past six months, the solution that worked for me was as follows:

1)  Right Click project

2)  Select Properties

3)  Select Configuration Properties > General > Platform Toolset

4)  When you get to Platform Toolset, click on the v110 value which will be in the right column. You will see a drop down appear which will allow you to select v90, v100, or inherit. Of course, v100 is the correct answer. Once v100 is selected, I don't believe you can back to v110 from within VS 2010. You would have to once again open in in VS 2012 to move it back to v110.