# What provides Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\io.h?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I installed Visual Studio 2010 and that gave me the C++ compiler

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
```

However when I tried to build an app (a Python package), I got an error about missing

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\io.h
```

On investigation, that `include` folder is almost empty (just three files).

What bit of Windows / Visual Studio do I need to install to populate the include folder?

---

What I'm trying to do:

```
pip install lxml
```

What happens

> Building lxml version 3.3.5.
>   Building without Cython.
>   C:\Python34\include\pyconfig.h(68) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory

Comment: This is not an uncommon install accident, nobody yet has explained what they did to their machine to make it happen.  Given the secrecy, I assume it has something to do with having a version installed on the machine before that was unlicensed and not cleanly uninstalling it.  Which leaves install information in the registry that says that parts of VS are already installed.  Rerun setup.exe with the /uninstall /force options to force a cleanup, then install again.  Never heard anything back after that so it probably works.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I'll try that. Yes, previously had Visual Studio 2010 on the computer before. I recall there were about twenty related-sounding items in the 'add-remove programs' menu, I removed them at random until I got bored.

Comment: No dodgy licenses or anything--this was at work (my home computer isn't even fast enough for Visual Studio).

Comment: @HansPassant which `setup.exe` do you mean?

Comment: Just setup, the VS installer.

Comment: Uninstalled and reinstalled twice, no progress.

Comment: Solved by following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460307/installation-of-visual-studio-2010-any-edition-installs-only-2-files-in-the-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by following [Installation of Visual Studio 2010 (any edition) installs only 2 files in the C++ headers directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460307/installation-of-visual-studio-2010-any-edition-installs-only-2-files-in-the-c)

- Uninstall Visual Studio 2010.
- Uninstall Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (despite the warning it gives).
- Open Registry Editor (`regedit`).
- Search for keys named `PaddedVersion`
- Remove any parent keys `VisualStudio\10.0\VC\Libraries`, or similar (note the version number `10.0`, which corresponds to `2010`). Delete all of these registry paths. The search for the `PaddedVersion` key is just to ease up this search.
- Install Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Doesn't SP1 need to be uninstaled before VS proper?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was conflict between Visual Studio 2010 Express (installed long time ago) and [Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools). `io.h` was not available in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include`, but was in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include` (so probably was skipped while installing Build Tools). When I added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin` to `PATH` it couldn't find `io.h`.

BTW. I think whole Visual Studio is not required, [Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) should work too.

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ Build Tools just work!Before I have installed Visual Studio 2017 Community.Then I install Visual C++ Build Tools 2015,it just works!