# Cannot open include file: 'io.h' when trying to install flask-bcrypt

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I get the following error when I try to install flask-bcrypt.  I am using Windows and Python 2.7.  How do I fix this error and get it installed?

```
Searching for flask-bcrypt
Best match: flask-bcrypt 0.6.2
Processing flask_bcrypt-0.6.2-py2.7.egg
flask-bcrypt 0.6.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\python_examples\realpython\flasktaskr\env\lib\site-packages\flask_bcrypt-0.6.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for flask-bcrypt Searching for python-bcrypt
Reading ...
Best match: python-bcrypt 0.3.1
Downloading ...
Processing python-bcrypt-0.3.1.zip
Writing c:\users\2c46f~1.0\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-30gixg\python-bcrypt-0.3.1\setup.cfg
Running python-bcrypt-0.3.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\2c46f~1.0\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-30gixg\python-bcrypt-0.3.1\egg-dist-tmp-v8alpt
bcrypt_python.c c:\python27\include\pyconfig.h(68) : fatal error
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory.
```

I visited [this page](http://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/15q5xj/anyone_have_a_working_version_of_flaskbcrypt_for/)
and manually installed py-bcrypt, but it didn't help me.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297777/what-provides-microsoft-visual-studio-10-0-vc-include-io-h) thread, maybe your problem is related to.

Comment: Maybe. But i have different versions of VS (i don't know where did they came from). Which one should I remove and reinstall again?