# Visual Studio 2010 include and lib folders contain almost nothing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, service-pack

The problem I'm experiencing is pretty self explanatory, after reinstalling VS 2010 ultimate edition, my include and lib folders aren't containing the expected number of files, which makes my c++ code unusable.

Before anyone points it out, yeah, I'm aware that this question has already been asked and answered, but the given answer didn't help me. The solution can be found in Kaba's answer here: [Installation of Visual Studio 2010 (any edition) installs only 2 files in the C++ headers directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460307/installation-of-visual-studio-2010-any-edition-installs-only-2-files-in-the-c). It is possible that I didn't clean my regedit properly, so I'm going to list the entries that I did remove. If that isn't the problem, I'm more than willing to try all and any other suggestion. No, reinstalling the windows isn't an option.

Here is the list of things I did while in regedit:

1)Searched for 'padddedversion' in order to find the needed entries.

2)Deleted the VisualStudio\10.0 folder found in HKEY_USERS

3)Deleted the VisualStudio\10.0_Config folder found in HKEY_USERS

4)Closed the regedit and reinstalled VS/SP1 after not finding anymore VS2010 folders while searching for paddedversion

Hopefully someone can point out my mistakes or offer an alternative.