# Visual Studio 2013 can't located header files when using the VS 2010 platform toolset

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

Yesterday I had to reinstall Visual Studio 2010 on a computer with both VS 2012 and VS 2013, because I needed to compile older code. The Visual Studio 2010 installation caused header file issues, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460307/installation-of-visual-studio-2010-any-edition-installs-only-2-files-in-the-c) . I followed the details provided in the answers, and got VS 2010 to install properly.

Now, when I run the VS 2010 version of `msbuild`, it compiles C++ code flawlessly. All the header files are properly installed in `c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include` .

*However*, when I open a project in Visual Studio 2013, and set the Platform Toolset to v100 (which is VS 2010), it can't find the header files! Although they are *right there*!

Answer (score 0):

This was originally a VS 2013 project, and I changed the platform toolset to VS 2010. This did not change the Include Directories property of the project, which was $(VC_IncludePath).

This macro is not defined by VS 2010, so the compiler can't find the include files.