# visual studio 2010 cannot include stdlib.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have been dealing with this problem the whole day. The problem happened after I uninstalled visual studio from control panel. I installed visual studio professional again from webinstaller. Then I started getting these error messages:

```
Cannot open include file: 'stdlib.h'
Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h'
Cannot open include file: 'afxwin.h'
Cannot open include file: 'math.h'
```

I tried to uninstall and install several times, but it didnt help, I tried to install visual studio premium, didnt help also, somehow these header files are missing from the directory where they are supposed to be. I also searched my computer these files does not exist...I tried to repair visual studio 2010 SP1...it didn't help also.

EDIT1:
I tried to create a win32 console application, and I left everything as the default:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    return 0;
}
```

And I got this compiler error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
```

Comment: try including <stdlib> intead.

Comment: @AnonMail didn't work :(

Comment: Actually, it should be <cstdlib> but stdlib.h (a C header) should also be found.  If not, your install may be wrong.

Comment: @AnonMail probably it is, do you have any idea how to fix that..

Comment: @AnonMail everything seems normal when installing, no error messages.

Comment: You should probably check the settings of your project. Try building a HelloWorld win32 Console Project and see if it finds these includes.

Comment: What do your `include`s look like?

Comment: @A.S.H please see my edits. Thanks

Comment: This is a bug in VS2010 installation, please refer this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460307/installation-of-visual-studio-2010-any-edition-installs-only-2-files-in-the-c

Comment: @Matt, Thanks, I will test this and let you know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to uninstall all visual studio versions that I have, I tried to clear all VS2010 related registry ...all of that didn't work.
The only solution that works for me is to copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\vc` folder from one healthy computer to mine.