# io.h not found in NetBeans 7.2

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to programming in C++ so bear with me here, please.  I'm currently working on a C++ project, using NetBeans 7.2 for Mac Lion.  For this project, my professor gave us the code to his main.cpp (which is written in C, according to the professor).

When I copy/pasted his code into my project, I got an error on the `#include <io.h>` line, stating "cannot find include file io.h", subsequently followed by other dependency errors.  I've searched all over the web, but can't seem to find the issue.  I'm using GCC/G++ compilers, which makes all the more confusing.  My professor says "io.h" has been around forever, so he doesn't see why it wouldn't be found.  I tried using the "locate io.h" command from the terminal.  However, it yielded far too many results for me to understand which, if any, were important.

I even tried copying and pasting the code into XCODE just to find that the "io.h" was still not found.

Any help with this matter would greatly be appreciated.

MakeFile...

```
#
#  There exist several targets which are by default empty and which can be 
#  used for execution of your targets. These targets are usually executed 
#  before and after some main targets. They are: 
#
#     .build-pre:              called before 'build' target
#     .build-post:             called after 'build' target
#     .clean-pre:              called before 'clean' target
#     .clean-post:             called after 'clean' target
#     .clobber-pre:            called before 'clobber' target
#     .clobber-post:           called after 'clobber' target
#     .all-pre:                called before 'all' target
#     .all-post:               called after 'all' target
#     .help-pre:               called before 'help' target
#     .help-post:              called after 'help' target
#
#  Targets beginning with '.' are not intended to be called on their own.
#
#  Main targets can be executed directly, and they are:
#  
#     build                    build a specific configuration
#     clean                    remove built files from a configuration
#     clobber                  remove all built files
#     all                      build all configurations
#     help                     print help mesage
#  
#  Targets .build-impl, .clean-impl, .clobber-impl, .all-impl, and
#  .help-impl are implemented in nbproject/makefile-impl.mk.
#
#  Available make variables:
#
#     CND_BASEDIR                base directory for relative paths
#     CND_DISTDIR                default top distribution directory (build artifacts)
#     CND_BUILDDIR               default top build directory (object files, ...)
#     CONF                       name of current configuration
#     CND_PLATFORM_${CONF}       platform name (current configuration)
#     CND_ARTIFACT_DIR_${CONF}   directory of build artifact (current configuration)
#     CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}  name of build artifact (current configuration)
#     CND_ARTIFACT_PATH_${CONF}  path to build artifact (current configuration)
#     CND_PACKAGE_DIR_${CONF}    directory of package (current configuration)
#     CND_PACKAGE_NAME_${CONF}   name of package (current configuration)
#     CND_PACKAGE_PATH_${CONF}   path to package (current configuration)
#
# NOCDDL


# Environment 
MKDIR=mkdir
CP=cp
CCADMIN=CCadmin


# build
build: .build-post

.build-pre:
# Add your pre 'build' code here...

.build-post: .build-impl
# Add your post 'build' code here...


# clean
clean: .clean-post

.clean-pre:
# Add your pre 'clean' code here...

.clean-post: .clean-impl
# Add your post 'clean' code here...


# clobber
clobber: .clobber-post

.clobber-pre:
# Add your pre 'clobber' code here...

.clobber-post: .clobber-impl
# Add your post 'clobber' code here...


# all
all: .all-post

.all-pre:
# Add your pre 'all' code here...

.all-post: .all-impl
# Add your post 'all' code here...


# build tests
build-tests: .build-tests-post

.build-tests-pre:
# Add your pre 'build-tests' code here...

.build-tests-post: .build-tests-impl
# Add your post 'build-tests' code here...


# run tests
test: .test-post

.test-pre:
# Add your pre 'test' code here...

.test-post: .test-impl
# Add your post 'test' code here...


# help
help: .help-post

.help-pre:
# Add your pre 'help' code here...

.help-post: .help-impl
# Add your post 'help' code here...



# include project implementation makefile
include nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk

# include project make variables
include nbproject/Makefile-variables.mk
```

Comment: Is it `#include <io.h>` or `#include "io.h"`?

Comment: Can you share your makefile? It is likely that you're not using the correct include path. (On my linux system `io.h` is in `/usr/include/sys/`)

Comment: I've tried both <io.h> and "io.h"

Comment: I've added the makefile to the original post. Forgive all the clutter, but I was struggling trying to get it posted (rookie mistakes)

Comment: Have you tried `#include <sys/io.h>`?

Answer (score 1):

Like said in another question, "In fact, io.h header has never been a part of ISO C nor C++ standards." ( [failing to compile a project, missing io.h file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211030/failing-to-compile-a-project-missing-io-h-file))
In this question, the top answer give a little library with a little io.h. I'm sure it will solve your problem. :-)

Comment: I will look into that link, thanks.  And yes, I have tried sys/io.h