# Compiling .c files generated by Cython into exe files

Tags: python, c, compilation, executable, cython

I'm newbie to python . I want to compile .c files generated by cython into .exe files . now i know there are programs like py2exe or cx_Freeze that can do the same but i want to make standalone executables (if possible) . now when i try to compile the cython .c file into exe
using

```
cl.exe  /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\Python\include -Ic:\Python\PC /Tctest.c /link /OUT:"test.exe" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MACHINE:X86 /LIBPATH:c:\Python\libs /LIBPATH:c:\Python\PCbuild
```

Compiling with cl as explained in 
[Can Cython compile to an EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581784/can-cython-compile-to-an-exe)

I get errors

```
c:\Python\include\pyconfig.h(68) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:'io.h': No such file or directory
```

please help

Comment: py2exe can be used to create a stand-alone executable, and is probably your best bet.

Comment: :/ Py2exe doesn't work for me . i'm using cx_Freeze for "freezing" @Claris

Comment: This looks oddly like this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211030/failing-to-compile-a-project-missing-io-h-file). I'd bet the issue is something like that. Here are two [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105482/compile-main-python-program-using-cython) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507592/making-an-executable-in-cython/22513682#22513682) that already discuss the general process of making an executable from Cython if you'd like to look at them.

Comment: They're different . n i guess @Claris is right . Cython is not for compiling executables . thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create standalone executables I recommend you to use PyInstaller, easily downloadable on Windows (I suppose you are using Windows) by command prompt with:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

(remember to add pip path to environment variables) or on Mac Os X:

> we strongly recommend that you install these using either MacPorts or Homebrew.

Documentation [here](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html).

Pyinstaller can compile .py files in standalone executables with the following command:

```
pyinstaller yourfilename.py -F
```

You can also add `--windowed` flag to make it a process (to hide console)

Comment: Note, that pyinstaller (or py2exe) is just the python interpreter packaged with your code and not a "real" standalone executable.