# Compiling Cython code yields... fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h'

Tags: python

I converted my python program into c code with Cython. Now I'm having trouble compiling it with the MS Visual studio compiler. I'm getting the error

```
C:\Python34\include\pyconfig.h(68) : fatal error C1083: 
Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
```

I'm running the command from the conosle

```
cl /c main.c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG 
-Ic:\Python34\include -Ic:\Python34\PC /link /OUT:"main.exe"
```

Comment: How did you configure Cython for MSVC? Do you have the same version of MSVC that was used to build your Python (and Cython)?

Comment: Is the `INCLUDE` environment variable set to the MSVC include directory? e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE`

Comment: @eryksun Do you mean set a second path variable to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE` ? Yes, I just tried that. I get the same error..

Answer (score 3):

I navigated to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include` on my computer, and the file `io.h` did not exist. It seems that that the problem is the file, in fact, does not exist!

According to this other answer, it is a POSIX compatibility library: [failing to compile a project, missing io.h file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211030/failing-to-compile-a-project-missing-io-h-file)

I'm not sure why this file can be missing. This other answer suggested reinstalling things: [Installation of Visual Studio 2010 (any edition) installs only 2 files in the C++ headers directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460307/installation-of-visual-studio-2010-any-edition-installs-only-2-files-in-the-c/16588726#16588726)

Edit: Everything just worked when I navigated to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2017\Visual Studio Tools`. There were `Developer Command Prompt for VS XXX` shortcuts. I opened one of them and all the compilation commands succeeded.