# "Building wheel for lru-dict" and "Running setup.py install for lru-dict" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, terminal, runtime-error

So I'm trying to download a program called TextAttack, which runs on Python, through my Anaconda terminal and I keep getting this error about "Building wheel for lru-dict (setup.py) ... error" and "Running setup.py install for lru-dict ... error". Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
  Building wheels for collected packages: lru-dict
  Building wheel for lru-dict (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\mtecl\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mtecl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gc4f2zmf\\lru-dict\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mtecl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gc4f2zmf\\lru-dict\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\mtecl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-fwm92t_z'
       cwd: C:\Users\mtecl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gc4f2zmf\lru-dict\
  Complete output (11 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'lru' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\mtecl\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\mtecl\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tclru.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\lru.obj
  lru.c
  C:\Users\mtecl\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lru-dict
  Running setup.py clean for lru-dict
Failed to build lru-dict
Installing collected packages: lru-dict, textattack
    Running setup.py install for lru-dict ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\mtecl\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mtecl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gc4f2zmf\\lru-dict\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mtecl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gc4f2zmf\\lru-dict\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mtecl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-uhdfg09i\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\mtecl\anaconda3\Include\lru-dict'
         cwd: C:\Users\mtecl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gc4f2zmf\lru-dict\
    Complete output (11 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'lru' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\mtecl\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\mtecl\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tclru.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\lru.obj
    lru.c
    C:\Users\mtecl\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\mtecl\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mtecl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gc4f2zmf\\lru-dict\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mtecl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gc4f2zmf\\lru-dict\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mtecl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-uhdfg09i\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See

- [Compiling Cython code yields... fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161251/compiling-cython-code-yields-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-io)
- ['io.h': No such file or directory during "pip install netifaces"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904828/io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)
- [Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cython-cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Originally links are posted by kroitor on https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/3578#issuecomment-410898645